# PackageInstaller.InstallConstraints (Caller has no access to package)

Tags: android

I used new API PackageInstaller.InstallConstraints.

When i run this code I get error (java.lang.SecurityException: Caller has no access to package "packagename")

```
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
                val requires = PackageInstaller.InstallConstraints.Builder()
                    .setAppNotInteractingRequired()
                    .build()

                installer.checkInstallConstraints(
                    listOf(context.applicationContext.packageName),
                    requires,
                    context.mainExecutor
                ) { result ->
                    println("REQUIRES APPPLY: ${result.areAllConstraintsSatisfied()}")
                }
            }
```

What could be the problem?

I checked my application package name and it is the same